# How to use object property in Android Room SQL?

Tags: android, android-room

In Room, we can make a query from DAO with fundamental data type like follow

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE name=:name)
fun fetchAll(name: String)
```

Is it possible to pass and object and use its property instead like following

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE name=:object.name)
fun fetchAll(object: ClassA)
```

I could not find anywhere saying how to do it, so i'm not sure if it is possible and how to do it. When I try it in Android Studio, it is indicating error

Comment: This could be an overhead to send an object to Dao rather than a primitive/ simple object like String in terms of the generated class; furthermore this can be achieved in the repository corresponding method... pass the object to the Repository, pass object.property to Dao in the query.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer helped you out. If so, I would appreciate if you could accept my answer  If you still have questions, feel free to ask 

Answer (score 3):

In RoomDatabase query you can try the query with multiple variations i.e.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE label LIKE :query")
  fun pagingSource(query: String): PagingSource<Int, User>

@Query("SELECT * from user WHERE region IN (:regions)")
    fun loadUsersByRegion(regions: List<String>): Flow<List<User>>

@Query("Select * from table_vehicles where key_id = :vehicleId")
 fun getVehicleDetails(vehicleId: String) : LiveData<List<VehicleModel?>>
```

But when you use **where** keyword you need to pass specific value or custom query for your results. Passing custom object may result into error.
As after the **":"** indicates value-parameter and you cannot add **model.id**.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Until now i think there is no way to pass an object as paramter but you can use @RawQuery

in DAO you can write

```
@RawQuery
LiveData<ClassA> loadFromUser(SupportSQLiteQuery query);
```

and create your query and pass to it.

```
SimpleSQLiteQuery query  = new SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT * FROM table where id = ?") , new Object[]{object.id})
```

and pass this query to DAO method.

```
yourDao.loadFromUser(query)
```